# How to create image of confusion matrix in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix, multiclass-classification

I am new to Python and Machine Learning. I am working about multi-class classification (3 classes). I want to save confusion matrix as an image. Now, `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix()` helps me to find the confusion matrix like:

```
array([[35, 0, 6],
   [0, 0, 3],
   [5, 50, 1]])
```

Next, I would like to know how to convert this confusion matrix to become image and save as png.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **OPTION 1**:

After you get array of the confusion matrix from `sklearn.metrics`, you can use `matplotlib.pyplot.matshow()` or `seaborn.heatmap` to generate the plot of the confusion matrix from that array.

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cfm = [[35, 0, 6],
       [0, 0, 3],
       [5, 50, 1]]
classes = ["0", "1", "2"]

df_cfm = pd.DataFrame(cfm, index = classes, columns = classes)
plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))
cfm_plot = sn.heatmap(df_cfm, annot=True)
cfm_plot.figure.savefig("cfm.png")
```

[image]

---

### **OPTION 2**:

You can use `plot_confusion_matrix()` from `sklearn` to create image of confusion matrix directly from an estimater (i.e. classifier).

e.g.

```
cfm_plot = plot_confusion_matrix(<estimator>, <X>, <Y>)
cfm_plot.savefig("cfm.png")
```

*Both options use `savefig()` to save the result as the png file.*

REF: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html

Answer (score 0):

To see classification report visually, maybe a better method rather than saving odd plots, is saving it as a table, or some table-like object.

See sklearn's [classification_report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html), it produces a nice table as an output, it has an argument `output_dict` which is `False` by default, pass this as true like

```
import json
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

def save_json(obj, path):
    with open(path, 'w') as jf:
        json.dump(obj, jf)

report = classification_report(y_true, y_pred, output_dict=True)
save_json(report, 'path/to/save_dir/myreport.json'
```

you can also try to get dataframe of that resulting dict with

```
import pandas as pd

report_df = pd.DataFrame(report)
report_df.to_csv('saving/path/df.csv')
```